# Why is user email null when signing into Facebook account, but not null when signing into Google account?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase to allow the user to sign in with either their Facebook account or their Google account. I have allowed the creation for multiple accounts under the same email address.

This is the method that sends the user to the next screen after successfully signing in with their Facebook account:

```
private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

And this is the method for sending the user to the next screen if they sign in with their Google account:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

So everything works fine, except when I use `user.getEmail()`, it returns null when signing in with my Facebook account, but returns the correct email address when signing in with my Google account. I am signing in both of those accounts under the same email address. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: User does not have email on his Facebook account or unverified email added on his account

Answer (score 5):

There might be 2 reasons for it

1. User has unconfirmed email.
2. User might have signed up with mobile number.

You are not guaranteed to get email from facebook